# ValueError: Expected a cuda device, but got: cpu

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to perform Reinforcement leaning using DPO but when i try to execute dpo_trainer.train() i keep getting this error , even though i checked

```
dpo_trainer.args.device
```

and it returns

```
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

I saw few solutions like moving the model to cuda or setting
'os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"'
but nothing helps, i am unable to find the issue. Below are the training arguments i am using

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    max_steps=100,
    logging_steps=10,
    save_steps=50,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=8,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=50,
    output_dir='./RL',
    lr_scheduler_type="constant",
    warmup_steps=0.03,
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
    fp16=True,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    run_name="dpo_mistral7B",
)
from trl import DPOTrainer

dpo_trainer = DPOTrainer(
        model,
        model_ref,
        args=training_args,
        beta=0.1,
        train_dataset=dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        max_prompt_length=512,
        max_length=1024,
        # generator=torch.Generator(device='cuda'),

    )
```